# X509 Certificate works in Windows and local machine but don't work in Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have authentication in asp.net web api 3.1 using X509 certificate.
The auth works in my local machine, but not works in linux docker.
Authentication must be open popup in browser and I must select usb token for auth.
I have this kind of appsettings file:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:4544",
      "Certificate": {
        "Path": "e-imza.pfx",
        "Password": ""
      }
    },      
    "HttpsDefaultCert": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:4545"
    }
  },
```

I add this auth in Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCertificate(options =>
```